# Solidity: ParserError: Expected pragma, import directive or contract/interface/library definition. uint private age; ^

Tags: solidity, remix, compiler, atom

I am using `Atom` together with `etheratom` and I don't get why this simple code won't run:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19

contract MyFirstContract {
    string private name;
    uint private age;

    function setName(string newName) {
        name = newName;
    }

    function getName() returns (string) {
        return name;
    }
}
```

It shows me the following error:

```
:5:5: ParserError: Expected pragma, import directive or contract/interface/library definition. uint private age; ^
```

Anybody an idea whats wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a `;` after declaring what version of solidity you're using. Use this `pragma solidity ^0.4.19;` in the first line instead. Consider using remix IDE in the future to help solve these small errors.

You can also use `view` on the `getName` function, this can be used as the function only reads data and will not cost Ether to run. Here is the updated function

```
function getName() view returns (string) {
    return name;
}
```

updated code

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

contract MyFirstContract {
    string private name;
    uint private age;

function setName(string newName) {
    name = newName;
    }

function getName() view returns (string) {
    return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Remix gives the exact same error message. (This is unsurprising because they both use the same Solidity compiler.)

Comment: Are you sure? When I compile it on the online editor I get no errors

Comment: I pasted the code from the question into Remix and got the same error.

Comment: To be clear, I was responding to "Consider using remix IDE in the future to help solve these small errors." I wanted to point out that Remix and etheratom behave the same in this case.

Comment: I've updated my answer with my edited code, try putting that in and it should hopefully work

Comment: The updated code is, of course, correct. My point was that Remix and etheratom both give the same error for the _original_ code.

Comment: Right, mis-read a bit. Thought you were getting the same error with the updated code! Glad it works! Remix gives helpful tips on where the errors are, I personally like using it but up to you.

Comment: I'm not the person who asked the question. I'm just making sure they know they don't have to switch to Remix. There's nothing wrong with etheratom.